# Clarification re: ZSH startup/shutdown files

Tags: shell, zsh, login, profile

I just upgraded to macOS Catalina and the new shell is ZSH.  So, since it's a fresh start, I'm trying to set up my shell environment with aliases, functions, etc. like I had in bash.  I'm trying to figure out what goes where, when I ran across this in the [documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Files)

> Commands are then read from `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`. If the shell is a login
>   shell, commands are read from `/etc/zprofile` and then
>   `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`. Then, if the shell is interactive, commands are
>   read from `/etc/zshrc` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`. Finally, if the shell
>   is a login shell, `/etc/zlogin` and `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin` are read.

The confusing bits...

- If it's a login shell it reads from `/etc/zprofile` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`
- Finally, if the shell is a login shell, `/etc/zlogin` and `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin` are read.

If I SSH to my Mac, it's a login shell.  So since I need to configure that, which files do I need to (or should) modify?  I guess to help answer that question it probably would help to understand the difference between `.zprofile` and `.zlogin` So, any guidance here would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*profile` files and the `*login` files are read under the same conditions: if and only if the shell is a login shell (and not invoked with an option such as `no_rcs`). The manual lists them separately because they're invoked in a different order relative to the `*rc` files.

The name `*profile` comes from `sh`, the [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) (which ksh, bash, dash and others are mostly reimplementations of with extra features). The name `*login` comes from [csh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell). Zsh is more sh-like but has features from both, so I guess that's why it supports both names.

Often it doesn't matter whether you use `*profile` or `*login`. But `*profile` files have the advantage that they're read before `*rc`, so if you have `*rc` content that depends on settings from `*profile` (for example, if your `.zshrc` calls a program which is in a directory that `.zprofile` adds to `$PATH`), you need to use `*profile` and not `*login`.

So put login-time configuration (usually mostly environment variables) in `~/.profile`, and interactive configuration (prompt, completion, key bindings, aliases, …) in `~/.zshrc`. You'll rarely need the other startup files.

Comment: That last sentence in the first paragraph is what should be in the ZSH documentation!